# Make curve disappear gradually after Mouse Up

Tags: eventhandler

I am trying to emulate a feature on GoodNotes that allows me to draw a glowing curve on a graphic and the moment I let go of the mouse, the curve gradually disappears.  See gif below.  The gif is a little jumpy because of the limited frames.  The curve disappears after maybe 3 seconds.

[image]

Thanks to @cvgmt the code below gets us part way there.  Now I want the curve to gradually disappear. This works pretty well on the first run... but can't reset the clock for some reason.

```
DynamicModule[{list = {}, d = 1}, EventHandler[Dynamic[
   Graphics[{{Opacity[.2 d], EdgeForm[Blue], FaceForm[], 
      Rectangle[{-5, -5}, {5, 5}]},
     Opacity[.1 d], Red, AbsoluteThickness[16], BezierCurve@list,
     Opacity[.2 d], Red, AbsoluteThickness[14], BezierCurve@list,
     Opacity[.3 d], Red, AbsoluteThickness[12], BezierCurve@list,
     Opacity[.4 d], Red, AbsoluteThickness[10], BezierCurve@list,
     Opacity[.5 d], Red, AbsoluteThickness[9], BezierCurve@list,
     Opacity[.9 d], Red, AbsoluteThickness[7], BezierCurve@list,
     Opacity[.95 d], Red, AbsoluteThickness[5], BezierCurve@list,
     Opacity[1 d], Red, AbsoluteThickness[4], BezierCurve@list,
     White, AbsoluteThickness[3], BezierCurve@list
     }]],
  {"MouseDragged" :> (d = 1; 
     AppendTo[list, MousePosition["Graphics"]]),
   "MouseUp" :> (d = Dynamic[1 - Clock[{0, 1, .01}, 3, 1]])
   }]]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the clock only runs once and doesn't reinitialize. You'll also need to reset list to empty every time you click. Add:

```
DynamicModule[{list = {}, d = 1, t0 =AbsoluteTime[],ti= AbsoluteTime[], 
  ti = AbsoluteTime[],decaytime=1}, 
 EventHandler[
...
  ,
  {
   "MouseDown" :> (list = {};),
   "MouseDragged" :> (d = 1; AppendTo[list, MousePosition["Graphics"]]),
   "MouseUp" :> (ti = AbsoluteTime[];d = 
      Dynamic[Clip[(ti + decaytime - Clock[{t0, \[Infinity]}])/decaytime,{0,1}]])
   }
  ]
 ]
```

This will reinitialize list when you click. It also initializes your clock at the time the code is run and lets it run to infinity, then updates `ti` so that the decay resets when you lift your mouse.

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with the curve disappearing at once when "MouseUp", the following will do the job:

```
DynamicModule[{list = {}},
 draw := 
  Dynamic[Graphics[{{Print[rr]; Opacity[.2], EdgeForm[Blue], 
      FaceForm[], Rectangle[{-5, -5}, {5, 5}]}, Red, 
     AbsoluteThickness[10], BezierCurve@list, White, 
     AbsoluteThickness[4], BezierCurve@list}]];
 EventHandler[
  draw, {"MouseDragged" :> (AppendTo[list, 
      MousePosition["Graphics"]]), "MouseUp" :> (list = {};)}]]
```

Comment: already got that one Daniel... trying to make it disappear gradually...almost got in in code above.  works once.